# Not able to delete database

Tags: database, postgresql

Trying to delete database using postgres but I am getting `dropdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "root".` command I am using is **"dropdb databasename"**. Please suggest

Comment: Don't do it as root. Do it as the database admin user. It is most likely named postgres.

Answer (score 5):

Regularly (for instance on Debian or Ubuntu) the *system user* `root` does not have privileges as *database user*.

Your error message indicates that you are trying to drop the database as *system user* `root`. Instead, do the same with the *system user* `postgres` - or with any *system user* that has `connect` privileges to the maintenance db (by default also named `postgres`) and the *associated db user* has the necessary privileges to drop the database in question.

```
sudo -u postgres dropdb databasename
```

[More details in the manual on dropdb.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-dropdb.html)

Answer (score -2):

the standard way to do it  is

> DROP DATABASE [ IF EXISTS ] nameDB

Comment: So is what the user trying to do